# Recover from a recover partition when F11 doesn't work and windows is corrupt

Tags: backup

I have someones presario V3000 laptop.  It has a D drive which is the recovery partition.  The user brought it to me and windows would no longer even boot up.  I could only reload XP and try to find a way to recover from the recovery partition.  However haven't been able to.

I read, hold F11 down when booting up, but that didn't do anything, and the other item I read is to create the CDs from the software installed in the OS from the factory.  Well that is the OS that went corrupt and is no longer there.  A new reloaded version of XP is there now.

Is there still a way I can either create recover CD's/DVD's or boot from the recovery partition?

Answer (score 2):

F11 is how HP says to initiate the recovery process for the [Presario V3000](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00809678&lc=en&cc=us&rule=21596&product=1817059&dlc=en#RecoverOS).  If that's not working, you have 2 options:

1. Buy replacement recovery CDs from HP (assuming they're still available), and run the recovery tool from them when they show up.  See the bottom "see also" section of the linked page for a link to the purchase option.
2. Give up, and live with your current XP install (or repartition your hard drive and reinstall, to get rid of that now-useless recovery partition and make sure your C: drive has the entire hard drive).

Before you choose, you should probably try that F11 trick a few times more just to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but I had a similar situation with my ThinkPad and still had a recovery partition on my hard drive. Here's what I did to make the partition useable.

Downloaded a copy of GParted.

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

I, then, changed the boot partition to the one that has the recovery and restarted and kicked off the recovery.

It's that simple. I'm assuming this works for computers that aren't ThinkPads, but your mileage may vary here.

Comment: I'm so glad I came across this answer. I reformatted an HP dv7 laptop and had some complications from not having some of the factory-supplied drivers. I do have a recovery drive, but as a result of reformatting, I didn't have access to the HP Recovery software to access the drive or make backup software. However, booting from the drive directly using GParted allowed me to do a full factory reset without complications!

Answer (score 0):

F11 when booting is one possible way. Also try others- particularly <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd>. Also <kbd>escape</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd>. Depends on the machine.

Otherwise, try using a live CD (maybe Ubuntu) to access the Windows OS or attempt to back up the recovery partition to DVD.

Answer (score 0):

[Smart BootManager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/btmgr/) should be able to let you choose which partition to boot from. Assuming the recovery partition is still stable, you can choose it and start the recover tools.  I used to use the floppy version all the time for computers that didn't know how to boot from CDROM drives.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, recovery partitions like these modify the boot.ini file.  Wha basically happens is that during boot, the OS loads a small program which sometimes puts the message to press the F11 just for a brief moment and if you don't it continues loading from the default partition.  If you press F11, it resets and loads from the recovery partition instead of the C: partition.

When you loaded XP, you wiped the boot.ini file and the small program doesn't exist.  In addition, sometimes the partition info is a little weird and sometimes when you format and load a new OS, it cleans up the partition info.  Basically, loading a OS probably screwed you.  Major lesson - image the drive before touching the drive.

That said, you can try and see if anyone has the same model and can look for the special INI file and loaders - it may be possible to fix it.  Dell had a fan guy that is famous for fixing this problem with their recovery system, don't know about HP.  You can also try and see if you can image the drive and then try and make the recovery partition the default boot by changing your boot.ini file - may work, if so, you will boot into the recovery mode.